# Cross Join with Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, join, where-clause

In Linq i must create a query with method only, i've got 2 tables :

- Students (LastName, FirstName, Result)
- Grades (Max, Min, Name)

I must select students (`LastName`, `FirstName`) and add to it the grade (`Result > Min && Result < Max`).

In the end I must have :

```
IEnumerable<T> T => LastName, FirstName, Grade
```

I try this :

```
var SAG = dc.Students
            .Where(w => w.Year_Result >= 12)
            .Join(dc.Grades, s => true, g => true, (s, g) => 
                  new { s.LastName, 
                        s.FirstName, 
                        Grade = g.Name
                                 .Where(w => (w.Min < s.Result) 
                                          && (w.Max > s.Result))
                        .FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

But with this request I've only 2 results but I must have 40 results.

Comment: Why "with method only"? And which navigation properties have you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
var SAG =
    from s in dc.Students
    from g in dc.Grades
    where g.Min < s.Result
    where g.Max > s.Result
    select new
    {
        s.LastName, s.FirstName, Grade = g.Name,
    };
```

(I do suspect you need either `<=` or `>=` in there somewhere.)

Comment: Grade is another table with not direct link, Grade = dc.Grades with upper and lower bound

Comment: @Hantse - Yes, I understand that. My query isn't doing a "direct link". It's matching between the bounds.